# I want to get count invoice_id where invoice_date = $today

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to get count invoice_Id's those enter toady, I try a query but i got nothing

This is my sql query, i have tried many time but got nothing

```
select count(invoice_id) 
from tbl_invoice 
LEFT JOIN tbl_order 
   using(order_id) 
WHERE tbl_invoice.invoice_date = '2017-10-18'
```

This is my controller which used this query in  php

```
$this->global_model->_table_name = 'tbl_invoice';
$this->global_model->_order_by = 'invoice_id';
$today_order = $this->global_model->get_by(array("invoice_date"=>'$todaydate'), false);
//var_dump($todaydate,$today_order);die();
$_SESSION["today_order"] = $today_order;
```

And this is my view file

```
<?php 
    $today_order = $_SESSION["today_order"];
    $today_order_count = count($today_order);
?>

<!------today order total count------->

<li class="dropdown messages-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        <span class="label label-danger"><?php if(!empty($today_order_count)){
                echo $today_order_count;
            }else{
                echo '0';
            }
            ?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why are you joining on the `tbl_order` table? From what I can tell it isn't required.

Comment: What mean `got nothing` ?? no data, any errors? do the query run ok direct on the db?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  got an empty array{0}

Comment: `select count(invoice_id) 
from tbl_invoice 
where tbl_invoice.invoice_date = '2017-10-18'` doesnt do the same ?

Comment: @PeterAbolins i try only tbl_invoice but i got empty

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes got nothing ,  i tried many time but got empty tables

Comment: **got nothing** == Maybe the table is empty, or maybe there are no records for the given date?

Comment: WHERE tbl_invoice.invoice_date =CURDATE()

Comment: What `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: @PeterAbolins no man i enter 42 invoices today

Comment: @TheHumbleRat yes bro i tried but got empty tables

Comment: @ Peter Abolins yes i use RDBMS

Comment: So... if you run the query directly against the database, then you get 42 records returned? But, when you run through `php` / `codeigniter`, then you get nothing?

Comment: `RDBMS` = Relational DataBase Management System. It could be `SQLServer`, `Oracle`, `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, ... they are all different. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Peter Abolins no if use $this->db->get(); then got all data but when i try to count invoice_id then i got nothing in both sql and php

Comment: @Peter Abolins i use mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account that the date is probably stored in `MySql`as a `datetime`. And, that contains a time as well as a date.

Try changing your query to cover the entire day:

```
WHERE tbl_invoice.invoice_date >= '2017-10-18'
     AND tbl_invoice.invoice_date < '2017-10-19'
```

Essentially, the dates would be stored as '2017-10-18 00:00:00', or with some other time-stamp.

Comment: how i use this  query in php please

Comment: because how i increase date in php if i use this query?